# Why did IOI not use bots to play the game?

Tags: ready-player-one

Why do they use actual workforce to play the game in *Ready Player One*?

If technology would have advanced so much, why could they not use simple bots to spam the game, trying out all possible combinations and places?

What sense does it make for actual humans to play by IOI company to win the egg?

Comment: isn't that the whole point of the movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not mentioned in the book or the film.

There are some actions that avatars can make to save some time - in the book, Wade had to run to the first challenge and set his avatar on auto-run while he researched his approach in another window.

The implication is that the OASIS doesn't allow bots other than those created in the game itself.  There's some magical items that can enhance powers/do awesome stuff, but players achieve things by themselves.

It's much like playing games on a console - you can't construct a bot to win your CoD matches for you - the platform simply doesn't allow it.

Comment: The OP might be saying that technology is so advanced, especially for IOI, that they could build a physical contraption that would mimic a human, and put that in the suit or have that manipulate the controller. The contraption would have faster reflexes, faster calculations, access to much more information, and some level of artificial intelligence. It would be like us building a contraption to press the right buttons on the CoD controller. Activision would never know that it wasn't a human.

Comment: In the scope of the book, this isn't a thing, however.

Answer (score 7):

Probably because bots would be banned.

Even if they could use bots (which I doubt),
the bots would be definitely banned. 
In all online games, from pokemon go to lineage, bots are identified and eventually deleted. So in this more advanced game, I suppose that such identification would be much easier.

So they replaced these bots with 'human bots'.

Comment: there could have been some hack , because the game was created long back and people had been playing ..and there was no development in game .

Answer (score 2):

### Because "bots" don't have intuition or advanced reasoning skills.

The Sixers are **real people** contracted to work for the IOI to win the *overall* contest and find the keys.

A "bot" might play one single game to destruction and still not find the key as we see in the final example where the object is NOT to win or reach the end but rather to wander around the maze and find an invisble dot.

> Well, there is a secret in Adventure **you don't find it by winning.**
>   You find it by wandering around in a dark room. Until you get to the invisible dot.

Comment: bots don't need intuition, they are suppose to solve problems by either brute-forcing the solution or following a simple algorithm. Since all you have to do is to find a place, brute force would be sufficient.

Comment: It's clear that these tests **do** require intuition and problem solving.

Comment: As a player of Adventure it should be noted that there is much more to triggering the easter egg. To get the dot you either needed to take the magnet to the proper page, or use the bridge to access an otherwise inaccessible area. You then had to take the dot to a specific room. In that room had to be at least one other object. If you just carried the dot there, nothing would happen. The amount of variables to make the situation occur is a little beyond the reasoning of a "brute force" play through or simple algorithms.